# how to copy elements in an array into sub arrays

Tags: java, arrays, grouping

I am trying do a grouping for a football tournament, but I don't know how to copy from the main array into sub arrays.

```
string [] groupings = {Arsenal, Chelsea, Barcelona, Real Madrid, Valencia, Juventus, Manchester United, Liverpool}
```

I want it in such a way that it will pick the first four and put in group one, and the last four in another group.
e.g

```
string [] group 1={ Arsenal, Chelsea, Barcelona, Real Madrid }
String [] group 2={Valencia, Juventus, Manchester United, Liverpool}
```

Please can anyone help me with this I am still new to programming.

Answer (score 4):

Use `Arrays` class [`copyOfRange`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOfRange%28T%5B%5D,%20int,%20int%29) method.

For ex :

```
        String[] grp1 = Arrays.copyOfRange(groupings, 0, groupings.length / 2);
        String[] grp2 = Arrays.copyOfRange(groupings, groupings.length / 2,
                groupings.length);

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(grp1));
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(grp2));
```

Comment: @JonSkeet Edited, my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

You can use loops. Like

```
string [] groupings = {Arsenal, Chelsea, Barcelona, Real Madrid, Valencia,
                       Juventus, Manchester United, Liverpool};
String[] grp1 = new String[4];
String[] grp2 = new String[4];
for(int i = 0; i<4; i++) {
  grp1[i] = groupings[i];
}
for(int i = 0; i<4; i++) {
  grp2[i] = groupings[4+i];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write your algorithm like this...

```
String[] grp1 = new String[groupings.length/2];
String[] grp2 = new String[groupings.length/2];

for(int i = 0; i<groupings.length/2; i++) {
    grp1[i] = groupings[i];
    grp2[i] = groupings[(groupings.length/2)+i];
}
```

This will complete your task in just a single `for loop` and this algorithm will be dynamic for creating 2 groups for any given size of array(even).